# How to change ID to Class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, class, cookies

What do you do to change a javascript from a ID to a Class? I tried to do it on my own but with no luck, this is what I ended up with. The original code was to show or hide an element and remember the users selection.

HTML:

```
<div class="popup" style="display:none">
    <img src="image-url.jpg" alt="alt text" title="title text">
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function setCookie (name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
    ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires : "") +
    ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
    ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
    ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}

function getCookie (name) {

    var cookie = " " + document.cookie;
    var search = " " + name + "=";
    var setStr = null;
    var offset = 0;
    var end = 0;

    if (cookie.length > 0) {
        offset = cookie.indexOf(search);

        if (offset != -1) {
            offset += search.length;
            end = cookie.indexOf(";", offset);

            if (end == -1) {
                end = cookie.length;
            }

            setStr = unescape(cookie.substring(offset, end));
        }
    }

    if (setStr == 'false') {
        setStr = false;
    } 

    if (setStr == 'true') {
        setStr = true;
    }

    if (setStr == 'null') {
        setStr = null;
    }

    return(setStr);
}

function hidePopup() {
    setCookie('popup_state', false); 
    document.getElementsByClassName('popup').style.display = 'none';
}

function showPopup() {
    setCookie('popup_state', null);
    document.getElementsByClassName('popup').style.display = 'block';
}

function checkPopup() {
    if (getCookie('popup_state') == null) { 
        // if popup was not closed
        document.getElementsByClassName('popup').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` gives you back a NodeList.  And a NodeList doesn't have a `style` property that's useful...all it has is `length`, and indexes for each node in the list.

In order to set the style of every `popup` that was found, you should iterate through the NodeList.  For example:

```
function showPopups() {
    setCookie('popup_state', null);
    var popups = document.getElementsByClassName('popup');
    for (var i = popups.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        popups[i].style.display = '';
    }
}
```

Of course, to hide them, you'd set the `display` to `none` instead.

If you know you'll only have one element to change, (1) why aren't you using an ID? :)  but (2) you can just say `document.getElementsByClassName('popup')[0]` to access the one element.  Note, though...if you ever have more than one, you'll only change the first one that way.

Comment: I'm very new to JavaScript, could you simply paste the new code? Thanks.

Comment: I've added an example for one of the functions.  (Note, i changed the name a little, as we're potentially doing more than one.)  For the other functions, the change would be about the same.

Comment: To display an element, don't set its *display* to "block", set it to "" (empty string) so that the function will correctly display elements with any kind of default or inherited display value.